# Draw Polygon with originX and OriginY set to center causes indieed displacement

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to draw a polygon with fabric, with the mouse, and previously in my application the originX of the object was "left" and the originY of the object was "top". Now, because it causes problems in other parts of the application, we have decided that we have to establish the originX and origin and both with "center".

This causes a displacement of the object when the creation of the polygon ends.

To see the problem, please uncomment the code. With the comments it works well with originX = "left" and originY = "top"

https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/bbg3oeyg/16/

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

draw_polygon(1);


function draw_polygon(id){
  editandoPoligono = true;
  canvas.selection=false;
  var mode = "add", currentShape;
  var puntos;
  newColor = "red";
  canvas.observe("mouse:move", function (event) {
     var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
     if (mode === "edit" && currentShape) {
     //currentShape.originX = "center";
     //currentShape.originY = "center";
     var points = currentShape.get("points");
        points[points.length - 1].x = pos.x;
            points[points.length - 1].y = pos.y;
            currentShape.set({
                points: points,
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
    }
 });
 canvas.observe("mouse:down", function (event) {
 var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
 if (mode === "add") {
     var obj = new fabric.Polygon([{
                    x: pos.x,
                     y: pos.y
            }, {
              x: pos.x + 1, 
              y: pos.y + 1
                    }], {
               fill: newColor,
               objectCaching: false,
                       selectable: false,
                   id: id,
               olvidar: "olvidar",
               strokeWidth: 0,
               originX: "center",
               originY: "center"
 });
 var circ =new fabric.Circle({
       id: "guiaPol",
       evented: false,
       selectable: false,
       top: pos.y-2.5,
       left: pos.x-2.5,
       radius: 5,
       fill:"black",
       perPixelTargetFind: true,
       originX: "center",
       originY: "center"
 });
 currentShape = obj;
 canvas.add(currentShape);
 canvas.add(circ);
 newColor= currentShape.get('fill');
 mode = "edit";
    }   else if (mode === "edit" && currentShape && currentShape.type === "polygon") {
 //currentShape.originX="center";
 //currentShape.originY="center";
     var points = currentShape.get("points");
 points.push({
    x: pos.x ,
    y: pos.y
 });
 puntos = points;
 currentShape.set({
   points: points
 });
 var circ = new fabric.Circle({
     id: "guiaPol",
     evented: false,
     selectable: false,
     top: pos.y-2.5,
     left: pos.x-2.5,
     radius: 5,
     fill: "black",
     perPixelTargetFind: true,
     originX: "center",
     originY: "center"
  });
  canvas.add(circ);
        canvas.renderAll();
  }
});


function pararCreacion(){
 if (mode === 'edit' || mode === 'add') {
    mode = 'normal';
    var obj = currentShape.toObject();
    currentShape = new fabric.Polygon(puntos,{obj});
    currentShape.set({
        id:id,
        originY: "top",
        originX: "left",
        fill: newColor,
        type: 'polygon',
        nombre: 'Objeto_' + id,
        perPixelTargetFind: true,
        strokeWidth: 0/*,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center"*/
     });
     var circleObjects = [];
     canvas.forEachObject(function (o) {
        if (o.id == "guiaPol") {
          circleObjects.push(o);
        }
      });
      canvas.remove(...circleObjects);
      canvas._objects.pop();

      currentShape.nombre = 'Objeto_'+id;
      if(currentShape.get('points').length>4){
        canvas.add(currentShape);
        fabric.Object.prototype.originX ="left";
        fabric.Object.prototype.originY ="top";
        currentShape.set({
          selectable: true
        });  
      }else{
        alert("Error");
      }
      canvas.selection=true;
      editandoPoligono = false;
      canvas.renderAll();
    }   
   currentShape = null;
   canvas.on("mouse:dblclick", pararCreacion);
 }
  canvas.on("mouse:dblclick", pararCreacion);

  };
```

Comment: Why you want to change `originX` and `originY` for all the objects?

Comment: Because if I modify the angle of an object with originX = "left" and originY = "top" with object., The object will rotate from the upper left corner, and I want it to rotate the object from the center.

I just realized that I can do this with object.rotate

Comment: I guess you don't need to change now.

Comment: Yes. The problem now is how to pick up the top, left coordinates of the object in question, because according to the OriginX / Y, it returns one or the other. We know that by default they are collected from the upper left corner, but when rotating, these coordinates change, because that corner has changed. If we put the originX / Y centered, it will return the coordinates of the center of the object, but that will affect the information that I present to the user. Right now I'm done a mess

Comment: Is there a method that returns the top and left of an object, regardless of the rotation that object has?